XCode SwiftUI App Preview not showing up (previews on other views work)
I feel like the answer might be obvious but I'm having a hard time.
I do not get a preview while on the main App struct.
I also cannot add a #Preview macro since it's expecting a View.
What am I missing?

You can use the view set in your App struct for the preview.

I ended up moving the whole WindowGroup content into a ContentView so I can add the preview.
The Swift Playgrounds on iPad automatically showed a preview for the app struct but I guess XCode on Mac does not.
This fixed my problem for the time being.
